# Export CLOB database field that exceeds 32767 char limit

Tags: java

I try to export content of table from a database to Excel.

In the table I have a column that holds imageURI data (that exceeds 32767 characters limit) or may hold line "Not Available" if the image is absent.

I do not need to export that image URI to Excel, just check if the image is present or not and export one of two lines for this particular column: "Present" (instead of the value of the cell) or "Not Available" (the value of the cell).

Here is the code that checks if the image is present or not (I'm using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to export data):

```
for (int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++) {
Cell dataCell = dataRow.createCell(i);
if(columnName.get(i).equals("IMAGE") && !result.getString(columnName.get(i)).equals("Not Available")){
    dataCell.setCellValue("Present");
}
else{
    dataCell.setCellValue(result.getString(columnName.get(i)));
}
}
```

The above construction gives me java.sql.SQLException.

How do I solve this?

Thanks.

### UPD:

The following construction:

```
for (int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++) {
    Cell dataCell = dataRow.createCell(i);
    if(columnName.get(i).equals("IMAGE")){
        dataCell.setCellValue("Present");
    }
    else{
        dataCell.setCellValue(result.getString(columnName.get(i)));
    }
    }
```

works fine.

Comment: If you don't want to export it, then don't include it in your `SELECT` statement (or just include a flag indicating if the image is present or not). This will also have the nice side-effect that your export runs faster. Btw which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I use database of SAP Cloud Platform. Looks like I'll have to add another field and put a flag in it that will tell if there is image or not in a record.

Comment: Can't you just do a `select case when image is not null then 1 else 0 end as has_image, ...`